# How to add custom css class name to the daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, css, daterangepicker

Is there any way to add a custom css class name to the [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) ? so that I can apply my own styles based on the my class name.
Like this,

`$('.dpick').daterangepicker( {
customClass: 'my-css', // This class name is not showing in the daterangepicker DOM.
opens: 'left',
autoUpdateInput: false,
//"parentEl": $(this).closest('div'),
locale: { cancelLabel: 'Clear'
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution,

```
$(document).find('.stdate').each(function () {
                $(this).daterangepicker(
                    {
                        //customClass: 'my-css',
                        opens: 'left',
                        autoUpdateInput: false,
                        //"parentEl": $(this).closest('div'),
                        locale: { cancelLabel: 'Clear' }
                        
                    }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                        picker.container.addClass('my-custom-css');                            
                    });
            });
```

Custom Style:

```
<style>
    .daterangepicker.my-custom-css {
        z-index:9999 !important;
    }
</style>
```